# how to create a element to load the json data in a loop using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom, foreach

i want to display the theaters like a child node element of the `demo` node and after i want to trigger the onclick event for other function using only JavaScript

how to use foreach for creating html dom for each array in json data

i want it display like this

```
<div id="demo">
  <div>theater in vizag</div>
  <div>sangam : 4K,DolbyAtmos</div>
 <div>sarat : 4K,DolbyAtmos</div>
 <div>melody : 4K,DolbyAtmos</div>
</div>
```

```js
let VizagData = '{"theater":[' +
'{"TheaterName":"sangam","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos" },' +
'{"TheaterName":"sarat","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos" },'+
'{"TheaterName":"melody","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos"}]}';
let VZMData = '{"theater":[' +
'{"TheaterName":"Srikanya","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos" },' +
'{"TheaterName":"kameswari","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos" },'+
'{"TheaterName":"IMAX","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos"}]}';
function search() {
  document.getElementById('th').innerHTML = myfunction();
function myfunction() {
 var value = document.getElementById('ct').value;
  var th1 = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementById('th').appendChild(th1);
  
th1.innerHTML = "theaters in " + value;
  return th1.innerHTML;
} 
}
function data() {
  var index = document.getElementById('ct');
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
if(index.value === "vizag"){
  const obj = JSON.parse(VizagData);
demo.innerHTML = obj.theater[0].TheaterName + " : " + obj.theater[0].Quality + "," + obj.theater[0].sound + "<br>" + obj.theater[1].TheaterName + " : " + obj.theater[1].Quality + "," + obj.theater[1].sound + "<br>" + obj.theater[2].TheaterName + " : " + obj.theater[2].Quality + "," + obj.theater[2].sound; 
}
  else {
    const obj = JSON.parse(VZMData);
demo.innerHTML = obj.theater[0].TheaterName + " : " + obj.theater[0].Quality + "," + obj.theater[0].sound + "<br>" + obj.theater[1].TheaterName + " : " + obj.theater[1].Quality + "," + obj.theater[1].sound + "<br>" + obj.theater[2].TheaterName + " : " + obj.theater[2].Quality + "," + obj.theater[2].sound; 
  }
}
var go = document.getElementById('go');
addEventListener('click', search);
addEventListener('click', data);
```

```html
<select id="ct">
  <option value="vizianagaram">vizianagaram</option>
  <option value="vizag">vizag</option>
</select>
<button id="go">GO</button>
<div class="th" id="th"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear: what's wrong with the output you get now?

Comment: **i want output like this**  `<div id="demo">
  <div>sangam : 4K,DolbyAtmos</div>
 <div>sarat : 4K,DolbyAtmos</div>
 <div>melody : 4K,DolbyAtmos</div>
</div>` but output i was getting is ` <div id="demo">sangam : 4K,DolbyAtmos</br>sarat : 4K,DolbyAtmos</br>melody : 4K,DolbyAtmos</div>`

Comment: i want output like the first html structure while compile

Comment: When I run it, the output I get is what you're looking for. Not sure why you're getting a different output.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the data and build the innerHTML. Something like:

```js
let VizagData = '{"theater":[' +
'{"TheaterName":"sangam","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos" },' +
'{"TheaterName":"sarat","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos" },'+
'{"TheaterName":"melody","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos"}]}';
let VZMData = '{"theater":[' +
'{"TheaterName":"Srikanya","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos" },' +
'{"TheaterName":"kameswari","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos" },'+
'{"TheaterName":"IMAX","Quality":"4K","sound":"DolbyAtmos"}]}';
function search() {
  document.getElementById('th').innerHTML = myfunction();
function myfunction() {
 var value = document.getElementById('ct').value;
  var th1 = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementById('th').appendChild(th1);
  
th1.innerHTML = "theaters in " + value;
  return th1.innerHTML;
} 
}
function data() {
  var index = document.getElementById('ct');
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var theatres = JSON.parse(VZMData);
if(index.value === "vizag"){
  theatres = JSON.parse(VizagData);
}
var innerHTML = "";
for (var obj of theatres.theater) {
  innerHTML += "<div>" + obj.TheaterName + " : " + obj.Quality + "," + obj.sound + "</div>";
}
demo.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    
}
var go = document.getElementById('go');
addEventListener('click', search);
addEventListener('click', data);
```

```html
<select id="ct">
  <option value="vizianagaram">vizianagaram</option>
  <option value="vizag">vizag</option>
</select>
<button id="go">GO</button>
<div class="th" id="th"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: how to add an id attribute in innerHTML  loop `"<div>"`.

Comment: @PentakotaLalithPrasad You can add it in to the innerHTML. EG: `innerHTML += "<div some-attribute=\"here\">" + obj.TheaterName + " : " + obj.Quality + "," + obj.sound + "</div>";`